# Gradient overlay over spinning elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do multiple things:

1. Properly scale the entire logo within the viewport, whenever I try it everything doesn't stay relative
2. Apply a purple gradient (to transparent) to apply just to the rings.
3. The rings rotate at different speeds and opposite directions, while keeping the gradient top-top-bottom

This is what it should look like:

[image: this is what it should look like]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Set a background color if needed */
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  /* Increase z-index for the title */
}

.core {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  /* Reduce z-index for the cores */
  background: linear-gradient(8c04fe, transparent);
}


/* Define different sizes for Core 1, Core 2, and Core 3 */

.core1 {
  width: 48vw;
  height: 48vw;
}

.core2 {
  width: 32vw;
  height: 32vw;
}

.core3 {
  width: 16vw;
  height: 16vw;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .title img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .core {
    width: 50%;
    /* Adjust the width as needed */
    max-width: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="core core1" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1mPcXOui7mzn4N60ZcFzmb1wFTTX_CcG9" alt="Core 1">
  <img class="core core2" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1_0TthVwoC9xjU7aYw3fn5dNjidqmVwrM" alt="Core 2">
  <img class="core core3" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=13hP0VO5kaEw5VkBiT2jhGG3upg78zum1" alt="Core 3">
  <div class="title">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1fXAwjJmIGRbKzAlKGGUmCFwAUYZnXtwx" alt="Title Image">
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried setting a gradient overlay with  background: linear-gradient(8c04fe, transparent) among other things, but nothing I tried seemed to actually be visible over the rings.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Please post your images to a photo sharing service so your demo shows the problem. Many of us can't see your Google Drive.

Comment: Accessibility tip: Alt text should be descriptive. If an image is for style only, leave the alt attribute empty rather than including text that doesn't make sense to a visually impaired user.

Comment: `linear-gradient(#8c04fe, transparent);` you have hex color ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not 100% what you were looking for but perhaps you can build from this.  Your images are not transparent so the gradient is behind them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
height:100vh;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.images-container {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(#8c04fe, transparent);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25vw;
}

.title {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.core-container {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
 padding: 0.25em;
}

img.core { 
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}


/* Define different sizes for Core 1, Core 2, and Core 3 */

img.core.core1 {
  width: 96%;
}

img.core.core2 {
  width: 64%;
}

img.core.core3 {
  width: 32%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .title img {
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  .core-container {
    max-height: 50%;
  }
}

.core {
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
}

.core.core2 {
  animation: spinleft 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinleft {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="images-container">
    <div class="core-container">
      <img class="core core1" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1mPcXOui7mzn4N60ZcFzmb1wFTTX_CcG9">
      <img class="core core2" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1_0TthVwoC9xjU7aYw3fn5dNjidqmVwrM">
      <img class="core core3" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=13hP0VO5kaEw5VkBiT2jhGG3upg78zum1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1fXAwjJmIGRbKzAlKGGUmCFwAUYZnXtwx" alt="Title Image">
  </div>
</div>
```